# Starting issue with 2007 F350 6.0 diesel

Tags: ford, starting, troubleshooting, ignition, diesel

Intermittently, when it's cold out and I'm starting starting the vehicle and then shutting it off the vehicle will start to crank while the key is in the off position. With the vehicle in the off position the starter should not crank.

I am lost as to what it could be. Seems like it might be the starter or ignition switch? How can I proceed with finding the cause?

Comment: Are you sure the starter is cranking or are you experiencing "dieseling" of the engine where it continues to run a little even after the ignition is switched off?  How long does it crank?  How do you make it stop?

Comment: When the ignition is in the 'OFF' position the engine cranks.  As in, the starter is turning the motor over OR it continues to run?

Comment: When the vehicle is in the off position the starter is cranking the engine like it wants to start and if you turn the key to the run position while it is cranking the vehicle starts. It will crank until you turn the key to run or the battery dies.

Comment: It really seems as though it's the ignition switch.  Not sure what else it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Check the start relay. I've seen other f-series owners complaining about this exact issue on this forum.